# How to update a variable’s value reactively from ‘Meteor startup’

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming

I am trying to add some general app configuration for a project I am working on, and I decided to save this on the database so that I can change them from some other place if things go wrong with the app, the main reason I am doing this is to add a 'maintenance mode' whenever I am making changes to the app or during deploys or something like that, the way I'm trying do this is with a variable I set with this code:

```
 Meteor.startup(function() {
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('configuracion', function(){
      configuracionGeneral = Configuracion.findOne({});
    })
  });
});
```

However, when I try to use it like this with iron router:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  console.log(configuracionGeneral);
  if(configuracionGeneral.vynoHabilitado=='habilitado'){
    this.next();
  }else{
    //Send to maintenance template
  }
});
```

I can use the variable configuracionGeneral with no problem and I see it on the console, but when I change the values of it on the database the variable doesn't change 'reactively', so I would like to know how can I change this variable 'reactively'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue lies with the fact that, [according to the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe):

> if the next iteration of your run function subscribes to the same
>   record set (same name and parameters), Meteor is smart enough to skip
>   a wasteful unsubscribe/resubscribe.

Therefore, your subscription is not re-run, and your callback is not triggered. You could try using this method, from David Weldon's [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  var handle = Meteor.subscribe('configuracion');
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    if (handle.ready())
      configuracionGeneral = Configuracion.findOne();
  });
});
```